# Random Forest: OOB error vs test error

Tags: predictive-models, random-forest, mse

I have a dataset composed by 124 observation and 13 variables. I need to predict the output of the response variable.

The observations have a time line. I mean that these observations are in order of time and I need to predict the values of the test set which is composed by 27 variables.

I'm using random forest but I'm not understanding why the OOB error computed with RMSE is very low (4.15) and the test error computed with RMSE is higher 20.1.

Is my model overfitting the data? Because since I'm using a random forest I used all the variables to fit the model.

Here I'm providing the graph of my model, on the left of the intercept you can find the train data and on the right the test data.

[image: Model with random forest]

Also here I'm providing the RMSE error for the train set and test set compared with different numbers of tree.

[image: RMSE error for different trees numbers]

Comment: This is a time-series problem because your data are arranged in time. This is also a forecasting problem because you want to use the past to make an informed guess about the future. Random forest is notoriously poor on these kinds of problems. You should use a [tag:time-series] or [tag:forecasting] model, because they are designed to be deployed against this kind of problem. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5brandom-forest%5d%20time%20series%20score%3a1%20answers%3a1%20is%3aanswer

Comment: Since I have some covariants that explains in a good way my response variable I used a single regression tree that makes good prediction, also better than random forest. Because in the single tree I selected the strongly independent variables. Instead in random forest I read that it useful to use all the variables. It makes sense that a single tree works better than random forest in this type of problems?

Comment: How do these models compare to a time-series approach?

Comment: For this project I need to solve with one of these approach: glm, gam or trees. So I do not consider the time series. I will take a look to them. What do you think about a single tree approach? Since i have a small dataset with only 2/3 strongly independent variables? This is the results https://imgur.com/a/VE75muc

Comment: It's up to you to decide whether or not a model solves your problem. We don't know any of the costs of an incorrect prediction or what the consequences would be for your organization.